# Defining custom functions in a storage model

Tags: entity-framework

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296754.aspx)

> You can define a custom function in the storage model by adding a
>   Function element that contains a CommandText element to the storage
>   schema definition language (SSDL) of an .edmx file. A CommandText
>   element is commonly used to provide functionality similar to that
>   provided by stored procedures, but the stored procedure is defined in
>   the .edmx file, not the database.

a) Does custom function simply send native query command ( this command is specified within `CommandText` element ) to the DB, or does it send a `CREATE PROCEDURE` command to the DB (  thus stored procedure created in a DB then contains a command specified within `CommandText` element ), and then in turn calls this DB's stored procedure?

b) What exactly is meant by *"the store procedure is defined in the edmx file, not the database"*? Perhaps that edmx file contains a blueprint from which it will create appropriate store procedure in the DB?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase *"the store procedure is defined in the edmx file, not the database"* is proceeded with 'similar to that provided by stored procedures'

So if you would create a stored procedure in your database and import it in the CSDL or create a custom function and import it in the CSDL, it won't make a difference for your CSDL.

But if you run SQL Profiler you will see that the CommandText is executed als regular Sql, not as a stored procedure.